# show that domain $\mathbb{D\setminus\{0\}}$ is not conformal equivalent to $A=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\frac{1}{2}\leq|z|\leq2\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

show that domain $\mathbb{D}\setminus\{0\}$ is not conformal equivalent to $A=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\frac{1}{2}\leq|z|\leq2\}$

any such conformal map will be analytic on $\mathbb{D}$, since $z=0$ will be removable singularity.but how to proceed furthr??

since $f$ is bijection between these two domain . then for some point $z'$
 with $|z'|=2,$ there exit point say $z_{0}$ in unit disk such that $f(z_0)=z'. $ hence $|f(z_0)|=2,$ but we also have $|f(z)|\leq2$ which is not possible by maximum mod princple,unless $f$ is constant. but this contraduct to fact that $f$ is injective.

is this correct expainnaton?

Comment: @ Thomas  no i have no idea of homotopy theory

Comment: you probably want strict inequalities in the definition of A, otherwise the problem is too simple, like you noticed.